# How to print multiple lines array in one height in Python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

I have a multiple lines like

```
NO = """###
###
###"""
LR = """###

###"""
```

and i have an `array = [NO, LR]`
i need to print it line by line. I try

```
for i in array:
    print i,
```

it print

```
###
###
### ###

###
```

but i need this:

```
######
###
######
```

thanks for help.

Comment: That's what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing "NO" and "RL" in a python terminal, you'll see '###\n###\n###' and '###\n\n###', respectively. The '\n' character is a empty line, so, that's why those strings are being printed with unnecessary lines. Make logic to not print unnecessary '\n' characters.